# Adjust pan is not working when calling the Async task in android

Tags: android, sqlite, asynchronous, keyboard, adjustpan

I have a tabbar and the activity contain a view that consists of a Edit text and List view. I have some values on the Sqlite database an Async task is used for fetching the data from Sqlite data base. When i click on the Edit text the Tabbar is also come to top with the Keyboard. But I remove the Async task from program the tabbar is not coming along the keyboard. How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: I solve this problem by using Thread instead of Async Task.